# Constant Bluetooth Problems with Airpods Pro 2 on Macbook Pro Late 2015. What Can I Do?

Tags: macbook-pro, airpods

So I recently upgraded from the Airpods Pro 1 to the Airpods Pro 2, after the old pair broke. The Airpods work fine with my iPhone XS, but it seems that my Macbook Pro is allergic to them. They connect fine but after listening to a YouTube or VLC video for a minute they'll disconnect and the entire Bluetooth module on the Mac will reset, disconnecting my Bluetooth mouse and keyboard as well. It's beyond frustrating.
I've tried everything: resetting the computer, resetting the Bluetooth module, hard resetting the Airpods Pro 2, but the problem returns every time.

As a note, I have a pair of original Airpods and this problem doesn't happen with them, and didn't happen with my old broken Airpods Pros. This problem just happens with the Airpods Pro 2.

Anyone have this issue? Is there anything I can do? I'm just about ready to return my new Airpods Pro.

Comment: Related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/456885/151404